# Failed to open a seesion for the virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

So I have installed VM and I was trying to make the screen resolution bigger and installed "sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms" on the terminal command.

It told me to restart the VM, so i did; but then when I try to run it again, I'm getting this error message and I can't run the VM;

The specified I/O port range intruded on an existing range. There is a I/O port conflict between two device, or a device tried to register the same range twice. (VERR_IOM_IOPORT_RANGE_CONFLICT

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There might be settings that are not configured properly. In the virtual box, go to the settings, then to the serial ports option. You can see 4 ports , all with user defined options. In the dropdown where userdefined is displayed select the different ports(COM1,COM2,COM3,COM4) for all the 4 ports and apply. Then try starting the machine again. The message wont be coming now.